# Simple way to avoid previous number in Math.random?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a random quote/color generator. I want it to avoid repeating previous color (in a simple/easy/understandable way as I'm a complete beginner in JS/jQuery).

Here is my code, I don't know what is wrong with it.

```
  var colors = ["#8ee5ee", "#ee82ee", "#469649", "#ff4444", "#ffa500", "#dddddd", "#efc3c8", "#d2d449", "#f91589","#906161","#875d39","#ffdab9","#d1e529","#3a718b"];

  var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

  var lastcolor = 0;

  while(color === lastcolor){
    color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length) + 1;
  }

  $("body").animate({backgroundColor: colors[color]}, 1000);
  $("#new-quote").animate({backgroundColor: colors[color]}, 1000);
  $("h6").fadeOut(1000);
  $("p").fadeOut(1000);

   });
  });
```

Basically, when I click a button (`#new-quote`), the current background color changes to another random color and so on. But now and then the color doesn't change as the machine chose the same number/color as the current one. I'm trying to avoid that!

Comment: And what is wrong?

Comment: What is previous color at all, if you are only getting one random color?

Comment: "Here is my code, don't know what is wrong with it." Why do you think there's something wrong? Do you get an error? What is the question?

Comment: It's only one random color but for instance, the machine chooses green. Then next time I click the button, green appears once again (because the machine randomly chose the same color/number again) and I'm trying to avoid that. Basically I want another random color after green, not green again. It doesn't happen often, I mean most of the time, after green comes orange then red, etc. But now and then the color repeats itself and it looks weird! as the quotes change along with the color!

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's some sort of loop around the code you provided. Then you shouldn't reset the color, but to assign it to the previous one.

```
var colors = ["#8ee5ee", "#ee82ee", "#469649", "#ff4444", "#ffa500", "#dddddd", "#efc3c8", "#d2d449", "#f91589","#906161","#875d39","#ffdab9","#d1e529","#3a718b"];

var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

while(color === lastcolor){
  color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length) + 1;
}

lastcolor = color;
```

And of course you should define your `lastcolor` at the beginning of the script. Place

```
var lastcolor = 0;
```

after `<script>` tag opens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, it doesn't work either using lastcolor = color. I don't know what's wrong! This is the above code:    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#new-quote").on("click", function(){

Answer (score 0):

You could use simply a new random value, because if you add one, you might get undefined if the random value is the index of the last element.

```
while (color === lastcolor){
    color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); // + 1;
    //                                         without ^^^^^^^ 
}
```

A better style would be one assignment with a `do ... while` loop.

```
var colors = ["#8ee5ee", "#ee82ee", "#469649", "#ff4444", "#ffa500", "#dddddd", "#efc3c8", "#d2d449", "#f91589", "#906161", "#875d39", "#ffdab9", "#d1e529", "#3a718b"],
    color,
    lastcolor = 0;

do {
    color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
} while(color === lastcolor);

lastcolor = color;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler method: Use `splice()` method to remove the current element from your `colors` array so that every time you run the code, the previously occurring element wont occur again.

```
var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

//from index = color, delete that element using splice(index, # of elements to delete)
colors.splice(color, 1);
//now colors array will not contain the colors[color] element

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    console.log(colors[i]);
}
```